# implementing instance of Read in haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass

```
data Alphabet = Zero | One

instance Read Alphabet where
  readsPrec _ ('0' : xs) = [(Zero, xs)]
  readsPrec _ ('1' : xs) = [(One, xs)]
  readsPrec _ _ = []
```

I'm getting

```
*Main Lib> read "0" :: [Alphabet]
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

I'm not sure how to implement the Read typeclass

Comment: Try `read "0" :: Alphabet` instead. You are trying to parse `0` as a _list_, and that fails.

Comment: cool that works for single tokens but i'd still like to implement `read "0101" :: [Alphabet]`

Comment: You need to implement `readList`; however if you want to interpret `"0101"` as `[Alphabet]` then you have ambiguity. "2 3" can be read as two `Integer`s but not as `[Integer]`, perhaps you can see an analogy with your situation.

Comment: is it possible for `read "0101" == [Zero, One, Zero, One]` or should i define this function without the Read typeclass?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Implement `readList` in `Read Alphabet` and `Read [Alphabet]` should pick it up. I wouldn't do it, though. `Read`/`Show` are meant to read/write data in a format that's basically Haskell code. You can use the `Read` parser machinery to define+use the parser but I wouldn't make it the "official" `Read`.

Comment: Note that `read "[0,1,0,1]" :: [Alphabet]` should already work. Also, `map (read . pure) "0101" :: [Alphabet]` should already work. I can't recommend to make `read "0101" :: [Alphabet]` work as well, since that would be rather different from every other read existing instance.